# Version drop down in VSTS build definition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have noticed a drop down with a version number in my build definition, this appeared few week ago(perhaps after a VSTS upgrade) in all of the build definitions. I could not find any reference for this in MSDN, Please explain the purpose of this.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the version of this build task. Some steps have more than one version for you to choose, such as "Visual Studio Test", "Copy Files" steps, etc. Some steps still have one version, like the "Nuget Installer".

You could choose different version of the step by clicking the dropdown list. If a new version of the step added, you will see a red flag beside it.
[image]

Update:

In the manifest file(the task.json file), set the version and preview like the below:

```
"version": {
    "Major": 2,
    "Minor": 0,
    "Patch": 1
  },
  "demands": [ "vstest" ],
  "preview": "true",
```

The "Major" set to 2 and the "preview" set to true, you will see "2.*(prview)" in your task.

Comment: Thanks Ting, Can you explain how to set this in a build extension? Do we need to set a flag in extension manifest to publish it as a preview?

Comment: @Bandara I have updated my reply and you could have a try about it.